# Spectrum of $X A X^\top$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ whose eigenvalues and eigenvectors are known, what can we infer about the eigenvectors and eigenspace of the matrix
$$
X A X^\top
$$
where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a known matrix?
I did some reading on perturbation theory, but problems of this kind seem to be not analysed.
Could certain conditions on $A$ (diagonal, rank one perturbation of diagonal etc.) lead to more conclusions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrices $A$ and $B$ are called *congruent* if there exists a nonsingular matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $B=XAX^T$. (See the book Matrix Analysis by Horn & Johnson, 2nd ed., Definition 4.5.4, page 281).

According to Sylvester's law of inertia, two congruent symmetric matrices with real entries have the same numbers of positive, negative, and zero eigenvalues.

Matrix $B$ is called a *compression* of $A$ if there exists a fat matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with $m<n$ such that $B = XAX^T$. (See the book Matrix Analysis by Bhatia, page 59).

If $A$ is symmetric, then, by Cauchy's interlacing theorem, the eigenvalues of $B$ are interlaced by the eigenvalues of $A$. (See Corollary 111.1.5 in Bhatia's book, page 59). Interlacing means that, for $j=1,2,\dots,n-k$ with $k=n-m$, we have
$$
\lambda_j^\downarrow(A)\geq \lambda_j^\downarrow(B)\geq \lambda_{j+k}^\downarrow(A)
$$
where the $^\downarrow$ indicates the eigenvalues are arranged in a decreasing order, i.e., $\lambda_1^\downarrow(A)\geq \lambda_2^\downarrow(A)\geq \dots \lambda_n^\downarrow(A)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. From the text, it seems for Cauchy's interlacing theorem we would need an isometry property of $X^\top$. Could anything be said in case $X^\top$ is not an isometry?

Comment: Yeah. You need $XX^T=I$. If not, then Cauchy's interlacing theorem holds for $(XX^T)^{-1/2}XAX^T(XX^T)^{-1/2}$.